# How to get username from discord Hikari Python

Tags: python, discord, bots

How to get a discord username like `bot.get_user(id)` would in discord.py?
I am using hikari, doing a JSON list of all the users in the server, I have their IDs but not the username and I would like it to update periodically.

```py
def retrieveUsernames():
  consoleLog(color.blue,"do get usernames") # log in console
  guild = "xxxx"
  jsonItem = cc.getJson() #get json object
  for key in creamCoin[guild]:


    user = # GET USER OBJECT FROM ID


    name = user.username
    name = bot.rest.get_user(int(key))
    print(key)
    print(name)
    #key acts as user
    jsonItem[guild][key]["username"] = name #update plain text username
  cc.updateJSONDatabase() #commit changes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hikari's API calls are asynchronous so you have to either: (1) call them using `await` in an `async` function or (2) use asyncio to call them from a non-async function, but it also requires hikari's event loop. All of Hikari's events are async functions, so you can just use await before the API function to call it. If you want to make periodic calls outside of a triggered event, I'd suggest using a separate thread or something like [APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/APScheduler/) to start a Cron-style service.

```py
import hikari
import asyncio
import threading

bot = hikari.GatewayBot(token='...')

@bot.listen(hikari.StartedEvent)
async def on_bot_started(event):
    user = await bot.rest.fetch_user(SOME_USER_ID)
    print(f'Main thread: {user.username}')

    # retrieve usernames in a separate thread
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    threading.Thread(target=retrieve_usernames, args=[loop, user.id]).start()

def retrieve_usernames(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop, user_id: hikari.Snowflake):
    call_async(asyncio.sleep(1), loop)
    user = call_async(bot.rest.fetch_user(user_id), loop)
    print(f'Separate thread: {user.username}')

def call_async(coro, loop):
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop).result()

bot.run()
```